# The value of 'form' must inherit from 'BaseModelForm'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to add dynamic choice field to adimin form, but I get an error:

```
The value of 'form' must inherit from 'BaseModelForm'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**(part of admin.py)**

```
class ReservationForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            self.fields['status'] = forms.ChoiceField(STATUS_CHOICES = ( (PENDING,'Pending'),(APPROVED, 'Approved'), (CANCELED, 'Canceled') ))

# Reservation

class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ReservationForm
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ReservationForm` does not extend `BaseModelForm` or any of its subclasses. Change it to:

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting 'ReservationForm' object has no attribute 'request' now.. Is it possible to get request into form?

Comment: No, but you can override the `get_form` method in your `ReservationAdmin` class to return a different form according to `request.user`. See the example in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **"forms.Form"**, you need to use **"forms.ModelForm"** with **"admin.ModelAdmin"** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"
                      # Here instead of "forms.Form"
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
                       # Here  　　　　
class ReservationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ....
```